# What is $\frac{dc}{dt}$ where $c(t) = (S\circ q)(t)$ for $S$ a surface and $q$ a plane curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces, function-and-relation-composition

Consider a parametric smooth surface:
$$S:R^2 \to R^3, \quad S(u,v)=(X_S(u,v),Y_S(u,v),Z_S(u,v)), \quad for \ u,v \in R$$
a parametric smooth **plane** curve:
$$q:R \to R^2, \quad q(t)=(X_q(t),Y_q(t)), \quad for \ t \in R$$
and the **space** curve:
$$c:R \to R^3, \quad c(t) = (S\circ q)(t)$$
Now, I believe that the following hold:
$$\frac{dq}{dt}\in R^2 \ , \ \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{u}},\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{v}} \in R^3, \quad \frac{dc}{dt} \in R^3   $$
$$\frac{dc}{dt} = \left. \frac{dS(u,v)}{dt}\right\vert_{(u,v)=q(t)}* \frac{dq(t)}{dt} $$

So obviously something is wrong. What kind of multiplication is $R^3*R^2$?

Is$\left. \frac{dS(u,v)}{dt}\right\vert_{(u,v)=q(t)} \notin R^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying Jacobian matrices, which are the higher dimensional analogs of the derivative for maps $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.  In your notation, $dq/dt$ is the $2\times 1$ Jacobian matrix of $q$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{dX_q(t)}{dt}\\
\frac{dY_q(t)}{dt}\end{bmatrix}$$

In your notation, concatenating $\partial S/\partial u$ and  $\partial S/\partial v$ into a matrix we obtain the Jacobian of the map $S$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial X_S(u,v)}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial X_S(u,v)}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial Y_S(u,v)}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial Y_S(u,v)}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial Z_S(u,v)}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial Z_S(u,v)}{\partial v}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

You'll find that the product of these two matrices will give you a higher dimensional analog of the chain rule. You should get the corresponding $3\times 1$ Jacobian for the composed map.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! However I have a question. In the second column of the second jacobian matrix, did you mean to use $X_s$ instead of $X_u$?

Comment: Yes it should be fixed now

Comment: What would I do if I wanted the second derivative of c(t)? $d^2c/dt^2$